# Which is the best way to ask for address history for credit checks

Tags: ux-methods

The current approach for understanding your address history for credit checks is by asking for how long you lived at particular addresses for the past x (depending on legal requirements) years.

I've seen the questions asked in two ways, with two different ways of inputting the data:

**1. Time spent at this address?**

Drop down (Years: 0, 1, 2, 3+) Drop down (Months)

[image]

**2. when did you move at this address?**

Drop down (Month) Drop down (Year)

[image]

**Which one do you think is the most intuitive/easy for the user?**

**Do you have any other recommendations?**

Thanks.

Comment: I would hypothesise that the 1st option comes from a developer requirement - they need to know the actual number of months because that's what is validated against, whereas the 2nd option is better for the user but requires additional (albeit minor) calculations in the back-end to work out how many months ago that equates to. So... developers will generally do what is easiest for them, not what is easiest for the end-user. You ask someone when they bought their car, they'll say 'January 2017' and not '24 months ago' for example.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Glad to see you are still active on the forum :) I was also thinking there might be a case for recognition vs recall. If I see a rough estimation of the time stayed at the address might be easier than remembering the exact date I moved in.?

Comment: Hi again Anton! To be honest your thought is why I only left a comment and not an answer - because I'm only hypothesising that it's easier for users to remember a date they did something rather than how long ago that was, but you're right; remembering that something happened 3 years ago is equally plausible. Hopefully someone has done some research into this and can authoritatively answer!

Comment: If you can remember which month you moved into an address in 1995 you have a very good memory!   - there should be a 'can't remember the month' option.

Comment: Is it possible that somebody moved from one address to another and then returned back? Thus he need to calculate total duration of several stayings or enter several periods of staying. If question sounds as to user like 'How long you lived?' most likely he is ready to calculate duration.